# Uploading multiple files in custom module does not work in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, zend-framework

I am new to magento 2. I have been overriding a module in which I am trying to post images through a form. Here is my **template file code**:

```
    <form action="somecontroller.." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--  here is the module code -->

      <div class="field review-field-media">
<label class="label"><span><?php echo __('Attachments') ?></span></label>
<div class="control">
<input type="file" name="review_media" id="review_media" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />
 </div>
</div>


</form>
```

and here is my controller execute method:

```
public function execute() {

        $returnable = parent::execute();

        $bgImage = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('review_media');
        $fileName = ($bgImage && array_key_exists('name', $bgImage)) ? $bgImage['name'] : null;

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        if ($bgImage && $fileName) {
            try {
                $uploader = $objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', ['fileId' => 'review_media']
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $imageAdapterFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')
                        ->create();

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

                $mediaDirectory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('review_images'));

                $model->setBgImage($result['file']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return $returnable;
    }
```

Now the problem is that when I upload multiple images through frontend and debug the code I get **null** in `$bgImage = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('review_media');`

But when I upload a single file `$bgImage` shows the requested file to upload. Even in case of single image file when `$uploader =$objectManager>create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', ['fileId' => 'review_media']);`
I get exception that image was not uploaded and the later code is not executed.

**IMPORTANT** : I am following magento's zend code so don't want to go with **php $_FILES[] method**

Million thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, could you please give some example how to create custom module to upload multiple files/images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so I got multiple files upload work by using `name="review_media[]"` as below

```
<input type="file" name="review_media" id="review_media" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />
```

and updated the **uploader** code to

```
$uploader=$objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader'['fileId'=>'review_media[0]']);
```

**review_media[0]** represent first media. You can access number of images through total file count by **$bgImage array**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="review_media" id="review_media" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />
```

Replace above code with following

```
<input type="file" name="review_media[]" id="review_media" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />
```