# Magento 2 : Upload multiple images from custom form at Frontend

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images from frontend with multiple fields.

I can able to save the **single image** but I would like to save **multiple images**.

Here is my controller.

```
 class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  protected $_resultPageFactory;
  protected $groupFactory;
  protected $uploaderFactory;
  protected $adapterFactory;
  protected $filesystem;
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context, 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    GroupFactory $groupFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 )
 {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
}

public function execute()
{
    //echo  "<pre>";

    /*$groupCode = $this->request->getParam('group_code');
    $groupTotalMembers = $this->request->getParam('total_members');
    $groupValidity = $this->request->getParam('group_validity');
    $groupMembersName = $this->request->getParam('members_name');
    $groupIndividualShippingAmount = $this->request->getParam('individual_shopping_amount');
    $groupShoppingAmount = $this->request->getParam('group_shopping_amount');
    $groupLink = $this->request->getParam('group_link');*/


    try{
        $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'member_profile_image'],['fileId13' => 'group_image']);
         // Not sure about above line !! I've add second param but not seems working.
        $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
        $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('group_image');
        $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
        if (!$result) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
            );
        }

        $imagepath = $result['file'];
        //
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }

    //print_r($uploader);
    //exit;

    //$group = $this->groupFactory->create();
    //$group->setCode('My Final123')->save();


    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;

}


}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Refer url:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198910/m2-uploading-multiple-files-in-custom-module-does-not-work

Comment: If you got a solution,please post answer