# Multiple Image browse in custom admin form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform

I have created a custom form in the backend and it is working fine for single image browse. If I select only one image then it is working fine. My requirement is, I want to select multiple images with the browse button. If there is any alternate solution then please let me know also.

[image]

Comment: refer this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198910/m2-uploading-multiple-files-in-custom-module-does-not-work

Comment: it is for frontend side form.I want to use in the backend.

Comment: Check this : https://www.softprodigy.com/store/article/how-to-upload-multiple-iimage-in-admin-backend-in-magento2/

Comment: @AasimGoriya Thanks for your link but i think this is not the proper solution. can you describe answer in more detail please

Comment: i don't have idea of "Multiple Browse Button", i asked my colleagues too. But alternate solution is you can allow Multiple Image upload.

Comment: You can refer magento code for the same, Magento is doing same while adding Product. Magento allows multi image upload.

Comment: is there any alternate solution? please help me!!! thanks

Comment: PLease post your code here

Answer (score 0):

If your form is rendering from UI form component then using `isMultipleFiles` option you can Defines whether multiple files can be uploaded.

For more reference go through [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fileuploader.html)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you use magento fileuploader UI componet then you need to set isMultipleFiles option value true.it's ddefault vlaue false,for more details please visit the magento devdocs link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fileuploader.html

hope it will help you.